# Affine scheme which is irreducible but not connected.

Tags: schemes, affine-schemes

Could you let me know the example of affine scheme which is irreducible but not connected?
I know affinescheme SpecA is irreducible only if nillradical of A is prime ideal.
But I have trouble with judging whether given scheme is irreducible...
I can tell which is integral, connected, reduced, more easily than irreducibility.

Comment: Consider the spectrum of $k[X,Y]/(XY)$. The ring is reduced not integral so the scheme isn’t irreducible. However, it is connected.

Comment: Thank you ! But I typossed...I wanted to know an irreducible but not connected affin scheme..sorry to bother my teacher..

Comment: Irreducibility implies connectedness. Indeed, connectedness and irreducibility are topological properties of the spectrum so are not affected by if we consider the underlying reduced subscheme structure. But a reduced irreducible scheme is integral, so that its ring of global sections is an integral domain, so contains no nontrivial idempotents. Thus the scheme is connected.

Comment: I agree if we assume reduced, irreducibility deduces connectedness.But if not reduced, are there any example of affinscheme which is connected but not irreducible?

Comment: No! If $X$ is a scheme and $Y$ is the corresponding reduced subscheme, $X$ is connected (resp. irreducible) iff $Y$ is connected (resp. irreducible).

Comment: I understood.From thishttps://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Irreducible_implies_connected I can say every irreducible schemes is connected. Am I right? Thank you my teacher.